# Minimum requirement for equality of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f,g\colon \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic and let $A = \{x\in \mathbb{R} :f(x) = g(x)\}$. The minimum requirement for the equality $f=g$ is

1. $A$ is uncountable.
2. $A$ has  positive Lebesgue measure.
3. $A$ contains a non-trivial interval.
4. $A = \mathbb{R}$.

I tried to use the identity theorem which suggests that set $A$ must contain the limit points of sequences of zeroes of both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. But I am confused between option 1 and 3. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make a diagram which of the conditions implies which other(s). You'll find that one of the conditions is implied by every other condition. That's the _minimum_ requirement among the listed choices.

Comment: Then the last three conditions imply the first. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Well, evidently we have $4. \implies 3. \implies 2.$. Why does $2.\implies 1.$ hold? (And, besides, why is 1. sufficient?)

Comment: Sorry..I have very little knowledge about Lebsegue measure. Only one thing I know here that a countable set has measure zero.

Comment: And positive Lebsegue measure implies A is connected subset of real line hence uncountable. Kindly correct me.

Comment: Right. And the contrapositive of that is that a set with positive Lebesgue measure is uncountable. $(C\implies N) \equiv (\lnot N \implies \lnot C)$, where $C$ means the set is countable, and $N$ means it's a null set.

Comment: But positive Lebesgue measure does not imply connectedness, for example the set of irrational numbers has positive Lebesgue measure (its complement is countable, hence a null set), but is totally disconnected (because its complement is dense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be enough to say that $A$ contains an accumulation point of $A$ itself: this would say a lot about the difference between real and complex differentiability ;)

Ps. I know an excellent book on the subject: "A course in Complex Analysis" of Fischer and Lieb, take a look at Ch.II

Comment: Yes, I know that point but option 1 and 3 confused me.

Comment: only one of them has to be correct. f a